# Writing SDC constraints for asynchronous clocks

Tags: timing, constraints, sdc

I am new to SDC constraints, in synchronous clock definition say A and B are synchronous with each other, then we can define `create_clock` on A port (input) and `generated_clock` on B (output) with `divide_by` option.

Now say X is input and Y is output, and both are asynchronous with each other.
Where such scenario will come in design and how to write SDC constraints on both input and output?

Comment: X and Y are clock ports too, right?

Comment: Yes, You can assume anything. I just want to know different scenarios and how to define clock on them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common way to define clocks synchronous or asynchronous to each other is the `set_clock_groups` command. The `create_generated_clock` command is not mandatory to make the clocks synchronous.

If clock A and B are defined as follows, my synthesis and STA tools classify them synchronous, but I don't rely on that and I explicitly define my clock groups.

```
create_clock           -name CLK_A -period 10 -waveform "0 5" [get_ports A]
create_generated_clock -name CLK_B -source CLK_A -divide_by 2 [get_ports B]
```

The clocks listed after the same `-group` switch become synchronous. Please note that CLK_A and CLK_B will also be asynchronous to any other clock (X and Y in this case).

```
set_clock_groups -asynchronous -group {CLK_A CLK_B}
```

Let's assume that clock X and Y have the following constraints.

```
create_clock -name CLK_X -period 20 -waveform "0 10" [get_ports X]
create_clock -name CLK_Y -period 15 -waveform "5 10" [get_ports Y]
```

If we put them into different groups, they become asynchronous.

```
set_clock_groups -asynchronous -group CLK_X -group CLK_Y
```

Now we have 3 clock groups in total. We could also define them with a single command as follows.

```
set_clock_groups -asynchronous -group {CLK_A CLK_B} -group CLK_X -group CLK_Y
```